# Magento 2 indexer:status Schedule Status always "working" instead of "idle"

Tags: magento2

Our new products don't show up (can't find by sku in search). We checked the indexer

```
bin/magento indexer:status
```

and found that the schedule of the "Catalog Product Rule" is always "working" instead of "idle", also found 10747 error in backlog.

[image]

My questions are

1. How to check the 10747 errors in the backlog? I checked

`var/log/cron.log`

and try to find it by

```
index
indexer
catalogrule_rule
Catalog Product Rule
```

but no luck

2. How to clear the Schedule Status "working" status to "idle", make it really work?

Comment: 10747 is just the backlog size, it’s not a number of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 10747 - is number of record in changelog
2. Run query in Magento DB `update mview_state set status='idle' where status = 'working';`

Comment: Not working @KAndy any other soluation.

Comment: @SavanDholu Can you add details (probably better in a separate question) on what exactly does not work?

Comment: When I run that query but still show backlog see the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/26fgf1t  not properly reindexing.

Comment: For the record, @SavanDholu either don't have cron enabled to process the backlog or an error is thrown when Magento tries reindexing (error which can be found in var/log/cron.log).